# Why is channukah not mentioned in Medrash chazal?

Tags: midrash, beis-hamikdash, chanuka, mishna

In Medrash chazal, (including medrash raba, tanchuma, toras kohanim etc…) there is no mention of the Yom Tov of channukah. This took place 100-200 years before Medrash was written. Although it is hinted at (for example by Haman’s Gezeira he did not choose kislev because of chanukkah) Yet there is not clear story or halachic Medrash that discusses this. Did I miss something? If not why not?
The first real mention is in Megilas Taanis and the Gemora.
Thank you!

Comment: The various midrashim were redacted in different centuries. Check out the infobox on this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midrash_Rabba

Comment: Thank you Kazi, but this would only answer Midrash Raba, if we look at a whole at all the Midrsahi chazal as a whole we should find some mention of חנוכה

Comment: For some weird reason you assume that midrashim are earlier than the Talmud. By the way, hanukkah is already mentioned [in the](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bikkurim.1.6) [Mishnah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Rosh_Hashanah.1.3), tough not in detail.

Comment: It is mentioned several times in the midrashim? Or are you after specifically just the story?

Comment: There are Medrashim written after the Gemora, Midrashi chazal is reffering to Sefri, sefra, toras kohanim, medrsah raba etc... these were written around the time of the mishna

Comment: Dov, thank you, the story is mentioned. I am referring to the idea of a Yom Tov instituted for Channukah.  the chasam sofer does say that Chanukkah always existed and those who say that it only became law after the destruction of the temple https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21994/mitzvah-of-ner-channukah-not-until-after-churban-habayis?rq=1

Comment: Bamidbar Rabbah - https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.17.2?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi

Comment: Bereishis Rabbah - https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.6.5?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi

Comment: Sifri - https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.297.11?vhe=Sifrei_Devarim,_Hebrew&lang=bi

Comment: Thank you @Dov again, I found these, there is also a reference in Esther by hamans lot. The first is not refering to channukah but building the beis hamikdash. The others is the last day of bringing the bikkurim it mentions the word channukah without what it is (I spent many many hours yesterday combing through medrash)
Thank you!

Comment: @Dov I suppose your first quote doesn't refer to the Chasmonean Chanukkah. [The other two are from Mishnah Bikkurim.]

Comment: What do you mean by "yom tov" of Chanukah? That it's something to be celebrated, or that it has the halachic status of yom tov?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya! The truth is there is also very little about Chanukah in Mishnayos and Talmud. Some suggest that this is because Chanukah is specifically connected to Torah Shebaal Peh, so even though nowadays we are allowed to write it down, Chazal still decided to make Chanukah be written down as little as possible.

Comment: Thank you @N.T. if you have a reference point for this it would really help!

Comment: I heard it in a shiur from Rav Moshe Einstadter shlit"a but I also recall seeing it elsewhere.